# Walmart Add to Cart XPATH

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a formula in Google Sheets that will check if the 'Add to Cart' text is on a given page. I starting by wanting to output the variable of the specific XPATH that the add to cart resides it but it keeps coming back as empty.

The formula below is what I am using to pull from `<span class="spin-button-children">Add to cart</span>`

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.walmart.com/ip/Centon-MP-SSD-480GB-SATA-III-2-5-Solid-State-Drive/51774264","//*[@id='add-on-atc-container']/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[3]/button/span/span")
```

I was able to have the price of the item fetched into Google Sheets using the below formula for this element `<span class="visuallyhidden">$52.99</span>`

```
=IFERROR(IMPORTXML("https://www.walmart.com/ip/Centon-MP-SSD-480GB-SATA-III-2-5-Solid-State-Drive/51774264","//*[@id='price']/div/span[1]/span/span[1]"),"")
```

The formatting of the SPAN elements is the same so I am unsure why the 'Add to Cart' button comes back empty even though the same thing should work from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the browser is modifying/enhancing the DOM as the HTML is parsed and rendered.

From the raw HTML, the following XPath should work:

```
//*[@id='add-on-atc-container']/div[1]//button/span
```

or more generically:

```
//*[@id='add-on-atc-container']//button/span
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA("https://www.walmart.com/ip/Centon-MP-SSD-480GB-SATA-III-2-5-Solid-State-Drive/51774264")), 
 "where Col1 contains 'Add to cart'")<>"", TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Interestingly enough this worked but now my price lookup formula is failing even though it worked earlier. Any ideas with this part? I can't seem to figure out how to get the above formula to work the the price and I have no idea why mine is returning blank when the code is the same as it was earlier on their site. `=IFERROR(IMPORTXML("https://www.walmart.com/ip/Centon-MP-SSD-480GB-SATA-III-2-5-Solid-State-Drive/51774264","//*[@id='price']/div/span[1]/span/span[1]"),"")`

Answer (score 0):

The XPath which you are trying is very dynamic.
Please try with this XPath-

```
//span[text()='Add to cart']
```

Comment: `=IMPORTXML(”https://www.walmart.com/ip/Centon-MP-SSD-480GB-SATA-III-2-5-Solid-State-Drive/51774264","//span[text()='Add to cart']")` gives a formula parse error